# How to apply a specific command

Tags: coq

For deciding less or equal relation between two terms ,I am using
command (destruct (le_lt_dec n n0)), Now I want to decide equality of these terms. I am using  (eq_dec n n0).I have error message. How this command can be apply?

Comment: can you add the complete example?

Comment: I have this statement (n0 - n0) <> S a.Want to convert it into (n0 - n0 = S a->False).I am applying this command(rewrite !Nat.neq_eqb ).

Comment: When I apply rewrite commands like 1.rewrite (eqb_correct _ _ l).2.rewrite (eqb_correct_conv _ _ l). they also have error message (these commands are not found)

Comment: There's nothing to convert? `<>` is a `Notation`: the goal should already *be* `n0 - n0 = S a -> False`, but Coq will not print it and will instead always "prettify" it by using `<>`. `Unset Printing Notations.` (or toggle the correct option in your IDE) and Coq will not use `<>` (don't permanently leave `Unset Printing Notations.` in your `.v` file!)